# Getting Inaccurate ask/bid Spreads During Live Markets with Alpaca API

Tags: rest, spread

It's been over a week now since I subscribed to the Alpaca broker's $9 data plan which means I shouldn't be getting data from just IEX anymore but rather I should be getting the more accurate SIP data right? Well here's my python code for pulling market prices (ask and bid) which is giving me very wide spreads.

```
 if __name__== '__main__':

    APCA_API_BASE_URL= "https://api.alpaca.markets"
    APCA_API_KEY_ID= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    APCA_API_SECRET_KEY= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    api = tradeapi.REST(
     base_url=APCA_API_BASE_URL,
     key_id=APCA_API_KEY_ID,
     secret_key=APCA_API_SECRET_KEY
    )

    aapl_last_quote = api.get_last_quote('AAPL')
    xom_last_quote = api.get_last_quote('XOM')
    tsla_last_quote = api.get_last_quote('TSLA')

    print("AAPL last quote: "+str(aapl_last_quote))
    print("XOM last quote: "+str(xom_last_quote))
    print("TSLA last quote: "+str(tsla_last_quote))
```

Here are some examples of results I got when running the above a few times. The quotes are all over the place, sometimes matching the actual live market quotes, sometimes not.  Appears I'm still getting fed IEX data.

AAPL last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 172.34,
'asksize': 1,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 172.32,
'bidsize': 4,
'timestamp': 1644266072449013311})

XOM last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 82.87,
'asksize': 4,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 82.86,
'bidsize': 2,
'timestamp': 1644266072546718096})

TSLA last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 960,
'asksize': 2,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 903,
'bidsize': 1,
'timestamp': 1644266072635263979})

AAPL last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 172.35,
'asksize': 3,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 172.32,
'bidsize': 4,
'timestamp': 1644266091652678817})

XOM last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 82.87,
'asksize': 2,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 82.86,
'bidsize': 5,
'timestamp': 1644266091715268409})

TSLA last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 948,
'asksize': 1,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 903,
'bidsize': 1,
'timestamp': 1644266092147050381})

AAPL last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 178.21,
'asksize': 1,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 172.37,
'bidsize': 6,
'timestamp': 1644266100742269106})

XOM last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 82.87,
'asksize': 2,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 82.85,
'bidsize': 1,
'timestamp': 1644266100829180588})

TSLA last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 960,
'asksize': 2,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 914.61,
'bidsize': 1,
'timestamp': 1644266100886873525})

AAPL last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 178.21,
'asksize': 1,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 172.36,
'bidsize': 4,
'timestamp': 1644266106879688339})

XOM last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 82.88,
'asksize': 2,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 82.86,
'bidsize': 1,
'timestamp': 1644266106550462539})

TSLA last quote: Quote({ 'askexchange': 15,
'askprice': 915.1,
'asksize': 1,
'bidexchange': 15,
'bidprice': 903,
'bidsize': 1,
'timestamp': 1644266106987356850})

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [get_latest_quote](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python/blob/d560c9b2278fdcf17a0687c14b1f33ab2aa2dc11/alpaca_trade_api/rest.py#L781)?
get_last_quote() is deprecated according to the source. Make sure you have the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a subscription instead of:

```
APCA_API_BASE_URL= "https://api.alpaca.markets"
```

try:

```
APCA_API_URL= "wss://stream.data.alpaca.markets/v2/sip"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing. You have to change from IEX to SIP. I was commenting on this post here - https://forum.alpaca.markets/t/real-time-callback-different-than-historical-quotes/11171/10

I'm not sure how anyone functions with bid/ask prices so innacurate. I can confirm it was fixed when I switched to SIP.